# Unable to create static binary because of undefined reference to dbus_*

Tags: go, static-linking, libpcap, gopacket

I get these errors when I try to statically link my Go program that uses Gopacket:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.a(pcap-dbus.o): in function `dbus_write':
(.text+0x103): undefined reference to `dbus_message_demarshal'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x119): undefined reference to `dbus_connection_send'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x122): undefined reference to `dbus_connection_flush'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `dbus_message_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x178): undefined reference to `dbus_error_free'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.a(pcap-dbus.o): in function `dbus_read':
(.text+0x1c3): undefined reference to `dbus_connection_pop_message'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x1e1): undefined reference to `dbus_connection_pop_message'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x1f6): undefined reference to `dbus_connection_read_write'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x262): undefined reference to `dbus_message_is_signal'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x27f): undefined reference to `dbus_message_marshal'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x2e3): undefined reference to `dbus_free'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.a(pcap-dbus.o): in function `dbus_cleanup':
(.text+0x350): undefined reference to `dbus_connection_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.a(pcap-dbus.o): in function `dbus_activate':
(.text+0x3fa): undefined reference to `dbus_connection_open'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x412): undefined reference to `dbus_bus_register'
...
```

Indeed these symbols indeed either do not exist `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.a` or show up as undefined. For example:

```
$ readelf -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.a | grep dbus_message_marshal
    42: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND dbus_message_marshal
```

None of these functions are called from my program, but are happening because of the dependency to Gopacket.

I have `libpcap` installed:

```
$ apt list --installed|grep pcap

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libpcap-dev/jammy,now 1.10.1-4build1 amd64 [installed]
libpcap0.8-dev/jammy,now 1.10.1-4build1 amd64 [installed]
libpcap0.8/jammy,now 1.10.1-4build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Is there anything else I need? Here's how I compile:

```
GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=1 go build \
    -ldflags "-linkmode external -extldflags \"-static\"" \
    -o bin/myprog \
    -buildvcs=false
```

If I do not include `-ldflags`, the program compiles, but it is not statically linked.

I am using Go 1.18.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: No, this is a Go program. How would I change how I compile this program with an answer to a C++ question?

Comment: The language is irrelevant. ldflags and libpcap are both linker related. The problem is the same, and the solution is the same.

Comment: libpcap is getting linked. Why doesn't it have these symbols?

Comment: If "it" is libpcap, it doesn't have those symbols because those symbols are part of the D-Bus library, which is used by libpcap's D-Bus capture support, they're not part of libpcap itself.  The libpcap *static* library isn't linked, it's built as an archive, as that's what static libraries are on UN\*Xes.  The ibpcap *dynamic* library is *dynamically* linked with the D-Bus library, so the D-Bus library routines aren't linked in to libpcap.

Answer (score 1):

> do not exist /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.a

They are not *in* libpcap.  They are *called by that version* of libpcap.

You will have to link with all of the libraries reported by `pkg-config --libs --static libdpdk` in order to statically link that version of libpcap with *any* program whether it's in Go or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like it is impossible to make a statically linked binary that uses Gopacket.

I updated the build command to use libdbus-1. This got rid of the undefined dbus_* errors:

```
GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=1 CGO_LDFLAGS="-ldbus-1" go build \
    -ldflags "-linkmode external -extldflags \"-static\"" \
    -o bin/app \
    -buildvcs=false
```

However, I got this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.a(libdbus_1_la-dbus-sysdeps-unix.o): in function `_dbus_listen_systemd_sockets':
(.text+0x200e): undefined reference to `sd_listen_fds'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x204f): undefined reference to `sd_is_socket'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

These functions come from libsystemd. I installed `libsystemd-dev`, but it seems like there is [no static library](https://www.mail-archive.com/pkg-systemd-maintainers@alioth-lists.debian.net/msg04939.html) for libsystemd.

Comment: No, it's currently impossible to 100% statically link with the DPDK library, as one of the libraries on which the DPDK library currently depends,, namely libsystemd, currently offers no static library.  Either 1) give up on 100% static linking (assuming Go tolerates that) or 2) give up on having a libpcap that includes DPDK support.  (I'm sufficiently annoyed with that DPDK code, for this and other reasons, that I'm tempted to make it optional in libpcap, so you have to explicitly say "support DPDK" when configuring libpcap.)

Comment: Do you know if this change was recent? Our app used to build with an older set of dependencies.

Comment: (Sorry, that should have been "D-Bus", not "DPDK", above.)  I don't know when libdbus started using libsystemd routines, but, on Ubuntu-22.04, `pkg-config --modversion dbus-1` reports "1.12.20" and `pkg-config --libs --static dbus-1` reports `-ldbus-1 -lsystemd`.